# ffmpeg Stream copy outputs wrong frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

When running the following command, out.mp4 has a framerate of 30.10, even though video.mp4's framerate is 30.00.  One thing that I noticed is that the duration of out.mp4 should be 00:00:06.39, instead of 00:00:06.38.  I also see that in the ffprobe output for out.mp4, the 'start' parameter is 0.020000 when it should (perhaps) be 0.000000, how can I resolve this?  I think this discrepancy might be due to the fact that the frame I am cutting at is not a keyframe, but I am really not sure what is going on :\

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 22 -c copy out.mp4
```

ffprobe for video.mp4

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:28.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2231 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2100 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

ffprobe for out.mp4

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.38, start: 0.020000, bitrate: 2307 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2254 kb/s, 30.10 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: Does the same happen when specifying the framerate with `-r 30` and/or when remuxing or reencoding?

Comment: @mashuptwice Hey, thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.  When I add the -r 30 flag (before -i), the FPS in the output is 30.10.  If I re-encode, starting at 22 seconds with -ss 22 the output also has 30.10 FPS instead of 30.0.  If re-encode the entire video, the FPS is 30.0 as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but if you want to adjust your start time to be on a keyframe, you can run the following `ffprobe` command to determine where the nearest keyframe is:

```
ffprobe -show_frames -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time -read_intervals 21%22 video.mp4
```

I've specified an interval between 21s and 22s as a starter but set it to your liking. If a frame is a keyframe, its `key_frame` entry is `1`. Use that timestamp and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Hey @kesh,

Thanks for the response.  I had a feeling this might be keyframe related, so this might put me on the right track.  When you say 'use that timestamp', can you elaborate?  Would I need to add it to concat.txt with a certain directive?  Or would I set a certain flag value on the output?

Comment: Sorry, I meant just use whatever `pkt_pts_time` (pts=presentation timestamp) for the keyframe you want to start at.

Comment: Another thing, re: `-f concat`. The doc says you must have all file's durations must be specified in the list file for the virtual file to be seekable (which is what `-ss` is essentially doing). So, you may need to do that.

Comment: Ah, I will give that a try.  I am generating concat.txt programmatically with python, so I guess I will need to get the duration of the clips that are being concatenated and insert this data into concat.txt.  I will try it, hopefully it works.  Regarding your other suggestion, I am a bit lost on how to "use whatever pkt_pts_time for the keyframe you want to start at".  I am sure this easy for someone that has used ffmpeg for awhile, but I am not quite sure how to actually do that.  I still have a lot to learn...I do read the docs frequently but they are extensive, as you know.

Comment: If you run the `ffprobe` command, you'll see what I mean (it's nothing fancy, really). On a separate note, I'm just about to drop a new [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) version with [`FFConcat` class](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/blob/main/src/ffmpegio/utils/concat.py). I'm looking for someone to testdrive it. If that's something you are interested, drop me a note on the github. Thanks

Comment: I took a look at your repo, nice work.  I am currently learning ffmpeg-python (while also learning certain intricacies of ffmpeg itself).  So far it has been pretty good for me.  I scanned your readme rather quickly, and yours might have some features that ffmpeg-python does not.  But I am currently feeling overwhelmed a little bit by ffmpeg, so learning a new API might be difficult for me right now.

Comment: @kesh - output `ss` is not a seek but a gate.